# Add .docx, .pdf, .txt etc as attachment with PHPMailer

Tags: pdf, phpmailer

I need to make possible for people to send their documents, be it `.docx`, `.pdf` or whatever from their computers, using PHPMailer. Of every solution I found, none of them worked for me. The error `Could not access file:` keeps showing up when using `$mailer->ErrorInfo`.

This is the code I have:

```
$mailer->From = $mail1;
$mailer->FromName = $name1;
$mailer->addAddress("gmfernandes@neo-e.com.br");
$mailer->Subject = $name1;
$mailer->ContentType = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$mailer->msgHTML($template);
$mailer->addAttachment($_FILES['anexoTrabalho']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['anexoTrabalho']['name']);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to [handle uploads correctly](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). Don't access `$_FILES` directly; use `move_uploaded_file` first. To save you the hassle of looking it all up, adapt [the example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps), the important bit of which I reproduce here:

```
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        // This should be somewhere in your include_path
        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
        $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
        $mail->msgHTML("My message body");
        // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg = "Message sent!";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help, but the `array_key_exists()` is not finding the 'anexoPrograma'. I don't understand why. According to the example it's the `input` name, right?

Comment: In the code you posted it's called `anexoTrabalho`.

Comment: Yes, I used it, but it still does not find it. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Have you specified the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form tag? If you don't have that, file uploads will not work.

Comment: Yes, I have that specified since the beginning.

Comment: Right at the top of your script, do this: `var_dump($_REQUEST, $_FILES);`. If anything in there is not as you expect, then the rest of your script doesn't matter - you need to fix your HTML.